# Is it possible to change scss to json?

Tags: javascript, json, sass

I would like to convert a scss file with variables to a json file. But I don't know if that is even possible. Could someone please give me some tips?

So I would like to convert this kind of scss file to a json file, the variables are defined in an other file:

```
.test {
    color: $test1; //#000000
}
.test1 {
    color: $test2; //#ffffff
}
```

The output should look something like this:

```
{
    ".test":{
        "color":"#000000"
     },
     ".test1":{
         "color":"#ffffff"
     }
}
```

Comment: There is no standard way to express the data in SCSS using JSON. What do you hope to achieve by converting it?

Comment: I would like to read out the json file by using pug. I know that sounds a little bit vague, but in my project it is neccessary.

Comment: @L.B — It's very vague. How would you expect `$foo: black; body > main { color: $foo; p { text-align: left; &>span { color: green; }}}` to be expressed in JSON? How would you expect to render it in the pug template? There really isn't enough information in your question to tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Quentin--After your example I see that I made it overcomplicated. I do however need a scss file with the variables generated to a json file. I edited my question

Comment: Re edit: Well that's invalid SCSS because the variables aren't defined, and you still haven't said what you want the output of it to be.

Comment: @Quentin-- Edited

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can.

Please check this package: https://github.com/ryanbahniuk/scss-to-json

Input:

```
// Font Sizes
$font-size: 14px;
$font-size-large: $font-size * 1.1;

// Colors
$text-color: #666;
$text-color-light: lighten($text-color, 15%);
$border-color: #123 !global; // use for all borders
```

Output:

```
{
  "$font-size": "14px",
  "$font-size-large": "15.4px",
  "$text-color": "#666",
  "$text-color-light": "#8c8c8c",
  "$border-color": "#123"
}
```

Source [scss to json github](https://github.com/ryanbahniuk/scss-to-json)

Comment: I saw this package and there are a lot of open issues and none is closed. And I get a lot of errors installing this

Comment: I can't get it to run on any of my SCSS … and the documentation says it only exports variables, not all of the styles.